# SQL for bucketing counts

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

I'm trying to create a histogram of people's reputations who ask questions on the site using StackExchange data explorer.

The following gives error message:

```
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that 
is not an outer reference.
Invalid column name 'lt_100'. ...
```

Suggestions appreciated

```
select
  case when Reputation < 100    then "lt_100"
       when Reputation >= 100 and Reputation < 200   then "100_199"
       when Reputation >= 200 and Reputation < 300   then "200_299"
       when Reputation >= 300 and Reputation < 400   then "300_399"
       when Reputation >= 400 and Reputation < 500   then "400_499"
       when Reputation >= 500 and Reputation < 600   then "500_599"
       when Reputation >= 600 and Reputation < 700   then "600_699"
       when Reputation >= 700 and Reputation < 800   then "700_799"
       when Reputation >= 800 and Reputation < 900   then "800_899"
       when Reputation >= 900 and Reputation < 1000  then "900_999"
       else "over 1000"
  end  ReputationRange,
  count(*) as TotalWithinRange
FROM Users
JOIN Posts ON Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId 
JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
JOIN Tags on Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 and Posts.CreationDate > '9/1/2010'
Group by 
1
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Sorry team, I've added the error message. The database is the StackOverflow data explorer (as stated in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `single-quotes` for the ranges being classified. If you use `" "` it would be treated as a column name. Also you should include the calculation in the `group by` clause.

[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/420751)

```
select
  case when Reputation < 100    then 'lt_100'
       when Reputation >= 100 and Reputation < 200   then '100_199'
       when Reputation >= 200 and Reputation < 300   then '200_299'
       when Reputation >= 300 and Reputation < 400   then '300_399'
       when Reputation >= 400 and Reputation < 500   then '400_499'
       when Reputation >= 500 and Reputation < 600   then '500_599'
       when Reputation >= 600 and Reputation < 700   then '600_699'
       when Reputation >= 700 and Reputation < 800   then '700_799'
       when Reputation >= 800 and Reputation < 900   then '800_899'
       when Reputation >= 900 and Reputation < 1000  then '900_999'
       else 'over 1000'
  end ReputationRange,
  count(*) as TotalWithinRange
FROM Users
JOIN Posts ON Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId 
JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
JOIN Tags on Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 and Posts.CreationDate > '9/1/2010'
Group by 
case when Reputation < 100    then 'lt_100'
       when Reputation >= 100 and Reputation < 200   then '100_199'
       when Reputation >= 200 and Reputation < 300   then '200_299'
       when Reputation >= 300 and Reputation < 400   then '300_399'
       when Reputation >= 400 and Reputation < 500   then '400_499'
       when Reputation >= 500 and Reputation < 600   then '500_599'
       when Reputation >= 600 and Reputation < 700   then '600_699'
       when Reputation >= 700 and Reputation < 800   then '700_799'
       when Reputation >= 800 and Reputation < 900   then '800_899'
       when Reputation >= 900 and Reputation < 1000  then '900_999'
       else 'over 1000'
end
```

Comment: Additionally remove the `Reputation >= xxx and` parts, it's a `CASE`:)

Comment: Thank you @vkp ! Also, I didn't realize the SQL distinction between single and double quotes.

Comment: also note that when you use `double-quotes` around column names, it would be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatley you can't alias the group by using '1' like you can in an order by. - To avoid repeating the case statement in your group by you can leverage the 'with' clause in SQL:

```
with data as (
select
  case when Reputation < 100    then 'lt_100'
       when Reputation >= 100 and Reputation < 200   then '100_199'
       when Reputation >= 200 and Reputation < 300   then '200_299'
       when Reputation >= 300 and Reputation < 400   then '300_399'
       when Reputation >= 400 and Reputation < 500   then '400_499'
       when Reputation >= 500 and Reputation < 600   then '500_599'
       when Reputation >= 600 and Reputation < 700   then '600_699'
       when Reputation >= 700 and Reputation < 800   then '700_799'
       when Reputation >= 800 and Reputation < 900   then '800_899'
       when Reputation >= 900 and Reputation < 1000  then '900_999'
       else 'over 1000'
       end as ReputationRange FROM Users
JOIN Posts ON Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId 
JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
JOIN Tags on Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 and Posts.CreationDate > '9/1/2010')
select  ReputationRange, count(*) as TotalWithinRange
from data
Group by ReputationRange
```

[Working Demo/Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/420762)